# How to display multiple flash messages in express Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm building an app using nodejs and express-handlebars and flash-message.

```
if(contact.daysLeft < 10){
                    console.log(`${contact.fName}\'s birthday is in ${contact.daysLeft} days`);   
                    req.session.message = {
                        message: `${contact.fName}\'s birthday is in ${contact.daysLeft} days`,
                        intro: 'It\'s almost time, '
                    }      
                }
```

The console.log() is able to print multiple messages but only the last message is getting rendered in handlebar Template.

```
{{#if message}}
    {{#each message}}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <strong>{{message.intro}}</strong>{{message.message}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```